# Problema de acentuação na geração de array com AngularJs

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, ionic

Estou com problema na hora de imprimir as formas de pagamento do usuário, eles estão sendo armazenados em meu LocalStorage com acentuação errada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
// PEGA $scope.formaspag (array2 no localstorage) E COMPARA COM OS CÓDIGOS DE FORNECEDORES_CONFIGURA_FRETE E IMPRIME NA TELA

        $scope.array1 = window.localStorage.getItem("tipos_pagamentos");

        $scope.array1 = $scope.array1.split(',');

        console.log($scope.array1);
```

Vou postar a seguir os códigos completos:

**Meu controller:**

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("nhaac").controller("formaPagCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicScrollDelegate, $http, $httpParamSerializer, $stateParams, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $ionicPopover, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicHistory, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, $ionicModal, sharedCartService, sharedFilterService, $cordovaOauth, $location, $cordovaDialogs) {

        $rootScope.page_id = "forma_pag";

        $scope.scrollTop = function () {
            $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("top").scrollTop();
        };
        // open external browser 
        $scope.openURL = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_system", "location=yes");
        };
        // open AppBrowser
        $scope.openAppBrowser = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_blank", "closebuttoncaption=Done");
        };
        // open WebView
        $scope.openWebView = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_self");
        };

        // Set Motion
        $timeout(function () {
            ionicMaterialMotion.slideUp({
                selector: ".slide-up"
            });
        }, 300);


        $scope.email = window.localStorage.getItem("email");
        $scope.name = window.localStorage.getItem("name");
        $scope.cidade = window.localStorage.getItem("cidade");
        $scope.estado = window.localStorage.getItem("estado");
        $scope.cod_cliente = window.localStorage.getItem("cod_cliente");

        $scope.total_pedido_tmp = window.localStorage.getItem("total_pedido");
        $scope.troco_tmp = window.localStorage.getItem("frete");

        var soma = parseInt($scope.total_pedido_tmp) + parseInt($scope.troco_tmp);

        window.localStorage.setItem("valor_troco_tela_troco", soma);


        $scope.teste = "teste";



        // INICIO LEITURA DE FORMAS DE PAGAMENTO

        // OUTRA COISA PRA ARRAY 2

        var targetQuery = ""; //default param
        var raplaceWithQuery = "";
        // TODO: Dinamics Promoções
        targetQuery = "json=promocao"; //default param
        raplaceWithQuery = "json=promocao";


        var fetch_per_scroll = 1;
        // animation loading 
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
        });


        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false; //readmore status
        var lastPush = 0;
        var array2 = [];

        if (window.localStorage.getItem("array2") !== "undefined") {
            array2 = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("array2"));
            if (array2 !== null) {
                $scope.formaspag = [];
                for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 10; lastPush++) {
                    if (angular.isObject(array2[lastPush])) {
                        $scope.formaspag.push(array2[lastPush]);
                    };
                }
                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);
            }
        }
        if (!angular.isObject(array2)) {
            $timeout(function () {
                // retry retrieving data
                $http.get("http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_pagamentos.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery, raplaceWithQuery)).then(function (response) {
                    array2 = response.data;
                    if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined") {
                        try {
                            window.localStorage.setItem("array2", JSON.stringify(array2));
                        } catch (e) {
                            window.localStorage.clear();
                            window.localStorage.setItem("array2", JSON.stringify(array2));
                            $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                            $state.reload();
                            $scope.$state = $state;
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.formaspag = [];
                    for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 100; lastPush++) {
                        if (angular.isObject(array2[lastPush])) {
                            $scope.formaspag.push(array2[lastPush]);
                        };
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    // error message
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: "error " + response.status,
                        template: response.statusText + "<br/>Ocorreu um problema na tabela de ofertas",
                    });
                }).finally(function () {
                    $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                    // event done, hidden animation loading
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                    }, 1000);
                });

            }, 1000);
        }



        $scope.doRefresh = function () {
            // retry retrieving data
            window.localStorage.clear();
            $http.get("http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_pagamentos.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery, raplaceWithQuery)).then(function (response) {
                array2 = response.data;
                if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined") {
                    try {
                        window.localStorage.setItem("array2", JSON.stringify(array2));
                    } catch (e) {
                        window.localStorage.clear();
                        window.localStorage.setItem("array2", JSON.stringify(array2));
                        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                        $state.reload();
                        $scope.$state = $state;
                    }
                }
                $scope.formaspag = [];
                for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 100; lastPush++) {
                    if (angular.isObject(array2[lastPush])) {
                        $scope.formaspag.push(array2[lastPush]);
                    };
                }
            }, function (response) {
                // error message
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "error " + response.status,
                    template: response.statusText + "<br/>problem: table ofertas",
                });
            }).finally(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                // event done, hidden animation loading
                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);
            });



        };

        // FIM LEITURA DE FORMAS DE PAGAMENTO


        // PEGA $scope.formaspag (array2 no localstorage) E COMPARA COM OS CÓDIGOS DE FORNECEDORES_CONFIGURA_FRETE E IMPRIME NA TELA

        $scope.array1 = window.localStorage.getItem("tipos_pagamentos");

        $scope.array1 = $scope.array1.split(',');

        console.log($scope.array1);





        // AQUI VAI ENTRAR O CÓDIGO DE ESCOLHER A FORMA DE PAGAMENTO

        // MODAL PARA TROCO
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/carrinho/modal/troco.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.troco_modal = modal;
        });
        //CODE FOR MODAL ENDS HERE

        $scope.checkItems = {}

        console.log($scope.checkItems);

        $scope.print = function () {
            console.log($scope.checkItems);
        }

        $scope.pegaFormaPagamento = function () {
            var array = [];
            for ($scope.array1 in $scope.checkItems) {
                console.log($scope.checkItems[$scope.array1]);
                window.localStorage.setItem("forma_pagamento_selecionada", $scope.checkItems[$scope.array1]);

                if ($scope.checkItems[$scope.array1] === "Dinheiro") {

                    $state.go('nhaac.troco');



                } else {
                    $state.go('nhaac.entrega');
                }
            }

        }


        // event readmore
        $scope.onInfinite = function () {
            $timeout(fetchItems, 500);
        };

        // create animation fade slide in right (ionic-material)
        $scope.fireEvent = function () {
            ionicMaterialMotion.fadeSlideInRight();
            ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
        };


        // animation ink (ionic-material)
        ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
        $scope.rating = {};
        $scope.rating.max = 5;



        //       }
        //       else
        //        {
        //            console.log("Enter in the ELSE DE FORMA DE PAGAMENTO");
        //  $location.path('#/nhaac/entrar');
        //           $state.go("nhaac.entrar3");
        //       }

    })

})();
```

Minha View:

```
<ion-view view-title="forma de pagamento" hide-nav-bar="false" page-id="forma_pag" id="forma_pag" charset="utf-8">
<!-- content -->

<ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll doRefresh()>

    <ion-list ng-repeat="ra in array1 track by $index" >
        <ion-radio ng-model="checkItems[ra]" ng-value="'{{ra}}'">{{ra}}</ion-radio>
    </ion-list>

    <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="pegaFormaPagamento(checkItems[ra])">
        CONTINUAR
    </button>

</ion-content>
<!-- ./content -->
```

E meu Index tá com a :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Ah, sim, vou passar meu PHP:

```
<?php


header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');



include 'database.php';

$query="select * from formas_pagamento ORDER BY nome DESC";


$result=$con->query($query);

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $count=0;
    echo "[";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
            $count++;
            echo json_encode($row);

            if($count!=$row_cnt)
            {
                    echo ",";
            }


    }
    echo "]";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

Como posso corrigir este problema de acentuação?

Lembrando que no banco de dados está tudo acentuado normal.

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Obrigado pessoal. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente você está enviando a resposta de seu `Backend` sem codificação, 
 você pode definir na sua chamada `get` o tipo de dado que irá vir na sua resposta.

Em seu `controller`, quando você está realizando o

```
$http.get('')
```

tente passar montar um objeto para sua requisição que contenha o `Content-type`:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url:'http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_pagamentos.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery, raplaceWithQuery)',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
      }).then(function(response){
.....
.....
....
})
```

Ou

Durante a fase de configuração da sua aplicação, `app.config()`, use

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
```

Documentação:

- [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http/)

Comment: nesse [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) tem como formatar as suas respostas.

Comment: Obrigado Fagner, valeu demais. Mas descobri que o erro é no cadastro e não na listagem... (burro eu), por isso abri a questão em: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192614/erro-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-xmlhttp-open-ou-no-php-usando-angujarjs-ionic Mas Obrigado mesmo! Já te pontuei!